# Sitecore site produces an error when I try to define a new site

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I want to change the default home page of Sitecore to MyPage. And I have tried the below code by placing it in web.config file

```xml
 <site
   name="GrandThornton"
   virtualFolder="/"
   physicalFolder="/"
   rootPath="/sitecore/content"
   startItem="/GTHomePage"
   language="en"
   database="web"
   domain="extranet"
   allowDebug="true"
   cacheHtml="true"
   htmlCacheSize="10MB"
   enablePreview="true"
   enableDebugger="true" />
```

And when I try placing the code it is throwing an error showing
[image]

Comment: Error is telling you that there is a missing config with site name "Grandtornton" and what you provided above sitename "Mywebsite", you need to find the site name "Grandtornton" in one of your configurations and fix that error, i think you are looking for wrong file try to find the site in sitedefintion.config

Comment: Even though if i set my site name as GrandThornton it is showing the same error.

Comment: If this is Sitecore8 - as your tag says - why are you defining a "site" in the web.config?? You should create a custom config file that patches the sitecore.config.

Comment: can you provide config file? Remove confidential info if any there.

Comment: Change  name="GrandThornton" to name="website" and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the configuration reader did not expect the `<site ... />` element to be located where it was found. Remove that node from your **Web.config** and the error will go away.

Sitecore site definitions are by default located in **App_Config\Sitecore.config** under `<sitecore>` -> `<sites>`.

You could add your site definition to the **Sitecore.config**, but there is an even better approach: [Sitecore patch files](http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/documentation/Sitecore%20Fundamentals/Patch%20Files/). Here's how you can apply it:

Create a new file in **App_Config\Include** and name it **SiteDefinition.config**. Add the following content in this file:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site patch:before="site[@name='website']"
        hostName="GrandThornton" 
        name="GrandThornton"
        virtualFolder="/"
        physicalFolder="/"
        rootPath="/sitecore/content"
        startItem="/GTHomePage"
        language="en"
        database="web"
        domain="extranet"
        allowDebug="true"
        cacheHtml="true"
        htmlCacheSize="10MB"
        enablePreview="true"
        enableDebugger="true" />
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Remember to change the `hostName` attribute to the domain name you want to use with this site.

The new site should work after this.